# Trying to filters an array of objects by an array of numbers with find my index and forEach doesnt work

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im trying to filter all the contact I have with an array of numbers I  want to remove. This should loop on every contact and remove the numbers not needed. Some contacts have two numbers and only one could be deleted but not the hole contact. I tried already to filter and see if the selected number is in an index but the forEach doesn't seem to be working any advice?. I don't think forEach returns something

```
const filteredContacts = contacts.filter(contact => numbers.indexOf(contact.phoneNumbers.forEach(phone => phone.number)) > -1);


//2 sample of all contacts
// contacts
  Object {
"company": "Financial Services Inc.",
"contactType": "person",
"firstName": "Hank",
"id": "2E73EE73-C03F-4D5F-B1E8-44E85A70F170",
"imageAvailable": false,
"jobTitle": "Portfolio Manager",
"lastName": "Zakroff",
"middleName": "M.",
"name": "Hank M. Zakroff",
"phoneNumbers": Array [
  Object {
    "countryCode": "us",
    "digits": "5557664823",
    "id": "337A78CC-C90A-46AF-8D4B-6CC43251AD1A",
    "label": "work",
    "number": "(555) 766-4823",
  },
  Object {
    "countryCode": "us",
    "digits": "7075551854",
    "id": "E998F7A3-CC3C-4CF1-BC21-A53682BC7C7A",
    "label": "other",
    "number": "(707) 555-1854",
  },
],
},
Object {
"contactType": "person",
"firstName": "David",
"id": "E94CD15C-7964-4A9B-8AC4-10D7CFB791FD",
"imageAvailable": false,
"lastName": "Taylor",
"name": "David Taylor",
"phoneNumbers": Array [
  Object {
    "countryCode": "us",
    "digits": "5556106679",
    "id": "FE064E55-C246-45F0-9C48-822BF65B943F",
    "label": "home",
    "number": "555-610-6679",
  },
],
},
]


//numbers not to have
numbers = [
 5557664823,
 1344043005,
 5467865467,
]


//Expected
     Object {
"company": "Financial Services Inc.",
"contactType": "person",
"firstName": "Hank",
"id": "2E73EE73-C03F-4D5F-B1E8-44E85A70F170",
"imageAvailable": false,
"jobTitle": "Portfolio Manager",
"lastName": "Zakroff",
"middleName": "M.",
"name": "Hank M. Zakroff",
"phoneNumbers": Array [
  Object {
    "countryCode": "us",
    "digits": "7075551854",
    "id": "E998F7A3-CC3C-4CF1-BC21-A53682BC7C7A",
    "label": "other",
    "number": "(707) 555-1854",
  },
],
},
Object {
"contactType": "person",
"firstName": "David",
"id": "E94CD15C-7964-4A9B-8AC4-10D7CFB791FD",
"imageAvailable": false,
"lastName": "Taylor",
"name": "David Taylor",
"phoneNumbers": Array [
  Object {
    "countryCode": "us",
    "digits": "5556106679",
    "id": "FE064E55-C246-45F0-9C48-822BF65B943F",
    "label": "home",
    "number": "555-610-6679",
  },
],
},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, you want to filter out some `numbers` from the contact's phone numbers. One solution to this can be approached using **[Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** over the `contacts` array and replace the `phoneNumbers` array with a new filtered array. For the filtering procedure we can use **[Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** and **[Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)** to check if a phone number belong to the list of numbers you want to filter out.

```js
const contacts = [
  {
    "company": "Financial Services Inc.",
    "contactType": "person",
    "firstName": "Hank",
    "id": "2E73EE73-C03F-4D5F-B1E8-44E85A70F170",
    "imageAvailable": false,
    "jobTitle": "Portfolio Manager",
    "lastName": "Zakroff",
    "middleName": "M.",
    "name": "Hank M. Zakroff",
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "countryCode": "us",
        "digits": "5557664823",
        "id": "337A78CC-C90A-46AF-8D4B-6CC43251AD1A",
        "label": "work",
        "number": "(555) 766-4823",
      },
      {
        "countryCode": "us",
        "digits": "7075551854",
        "id": "E998F7A3-CC3C-4CF1-BC21-A53682BC7C7A",
        "label": "other",
        "number": "(707) 555-1854",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "contactType": "person",
    "firstName": "David",
    "id": "E94CD15C-7964-4A9B-8AC4-10D7CFB791FD",
    "imageAvailable": false,
    "lastName": "Taylor",
    "name": "David Taylor",
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "countryCode": "us",
        "digits": "5556106679",
        "id": "FE064E55-C246-45F0-9C48-822BF65B943F",
        "label": "home",
        "number": "555-610-6679",
      },
    ],
  },
];

// Numbers to filter out.
const numsToFilterOut = [5557664823];

let res = contacts.map(contact =>
{
    contact.phoneNumbers = contact.phoneNumbers.filter(
        // Unary plus is used to coerces (cast) the string to number.
        phone => !numsToFilterOut.includes(+phone.digits)
    );

    return contact;
});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```